# Resources in drawable directory not work properly

Tags: android

## Context

This problem happened after I migrated an android application from `App to AppCompact` using refactor option in Android Studio 3.3 (It had been using nonsupport library version before), this process including manually changed deprecated APIs and so on.

I also updated `compileSdkVersion` from 27 to 28 and support library version from 27.1.1 to 28.0.0.

**Everything work totally fine before I migrated and update compileSdkVersion and support library version.**

## Problem

After I migrated, I'm able to run in on my phone.  However, I noticed that the Buttons that have been styled don't look like the way they should be.

From [image: What it should be]

To [image: What it is right now]

This is one of the styles that I applied to button.

styles.xml

```
<style name="GraderButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/button_background</item>
    <item name="android:padding">13dip</item>
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/THSarabunNew Bold.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

And this is one of the button that the above style was applied to.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
    style="@style/GraderButton"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/action_scan"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progressStatus"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineMiddle"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39999998" />
```

Apparently, from some test I did, `shape` resources that are applied to `background` is not recognized or not work properly.  From that I investigated.

- References to those resources in `drawable` directory are perfectly working, no red text error, autocomplete working for every resource in the drawable directory.
- However, when I hold cursor above those resources name, it said `Empty StateList` for `shape` is wrapped in `selector`[image]
  for other resources that aren't wrapped in selector, it just shows the full path to a resource file in red text. **Everything work with style** except `shape` that is applied to the button's background[image]
- Everything in style other than the things that use resources from drawable works perfectly. (textSize, padding and etc.)

  ## Additional information
- There is only one `drawable` directory in this project, there isn't any `drawable-xx`.
- Before I migrated the application still have android support library but I think it hadn't been used.  `android.app.Activity`, `android.app.Fragment`, `android.widget.ImageView` had been used.

Comment: use item name="android:background" instead of item name="background"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here in GraderButton style there is

```
item name="background"
```

which is not attribute of Button (Widget)
So, here we have to set background of button using:-

```
item name="android:background"
```